# How to integrate :missed days with :committed days in habits.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integer, rails-activerecord, days

How can we integrate `t.integer :missed` with `t.text :committed` so that

1. when a User checks off he `:missed` 3 `:committed` days in a `:level` he has to restart the `:level`?
2. for each `:missed` day he checks off, an additional `:committed` day is added back into the `:level` so that he must make it up before advancing?

Each habit has 5 levels before `"Mastery"` is achieved!

```html
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 before_save :set_level
 acts_as_taggable
 serialize :committed, Array

  def self.comitted_for_today
    today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end

 def levels
   committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
   n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }

  case n_days   
   when 0..9
     1
   when 10..24
     2
   when 25..44
     3
   when 45..69
     4
   when 70..99
     5
   else
     "Mastery"
  end
 end

private
 def set_level
  self.level = levels
 end 
end
```

I'm guessing we would have to distinguish `:missed` from `:missed` here depending on what level it is referring to.

**habits/_form.html.erb**

```html
  <label> Missed: </label>
  <div>
  <label> Level 1: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label> Level 2: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label> Level 3: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label> Level 4: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label> Level 5: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  <%= f.check_box :missed %>
  </div>
```

**habits_controller.rb**

```html
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @habits = Habit.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started DESC")
      @habits = current_user.habits
    end
  end
                                              
private
                                              
    def habit_params
      params.require(:habit).permit(:missed, :left, :level, :date_started, :trigger, :target, :positive, :negative, :tag_list, :committed => [])
    end
end
```

**_create_habits.rb**

```html
class CreateHabits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :habits do |t|
      t.integer :missed
      t.integer :level
      t.text :committed
      t.datetime :date_started
      t.string :trigger
      t.string :target
      t.string :positive
      t.string :negative
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :habits, :users
    add_index :habits, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

`:committed` works perfectly, but right now `:missed` serves no purpose. Please help me add the appropriate logic to integrate `:missed` with `:committed`.

**Thank you so much for your time!**

### **UPDATE**

@Dimitry_N's answer doesn't achieve either 1) or 2) of this question as much as I've tried to make it work. Maybe you'll have a better luck incorporating his logic. With his answer I also get this error: [How to fix level.rb to work with :committed days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933272/how-to-fix-level-rb-to-work-with-committed-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should break the question done because this is a lot to ask for in one question. Dimitry_N seemed to be on the right track, but you'll need to add some of your logic to the levels model now. Please chat with me if you want to go over the details.

Answer (score 3):

I think the program design has to be slightly re-evaluated. I believe that `levels` and `days` should be separate models with columns like `level` and `missed` (following the concepts of **SRP** as @dgilperez mentioned in his comment). Thus, we end up with four models: `User`, `Habit`, `Level` and `Day`,  with the following associations:

- **User**: `has_many :habits`, `has_many :levels`
- **Habit**: `belongs_to:user`, `has_many :levels` and   `has_many   :days, through: :levels #for being able to access Habit.find(*).days`
- **Level**: `belongs_to :user`, `belongs_to :habit` and `has_many :days`
- **Day**: `belongs_to :level`, `belongs_to :habit`

With these associations, you can create a form with **nested attributes**. There is an [awesome RailCast explaining nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1).

```
<%= form_for @habit do |habit| %>
  <% 5.times.each_with_index do |number, index| %> 
    <h1>Level <%= index + 1 %></h1>
    <%= habit.fields_for :levels do |level| %>
      <%= level.fields_for :days do |day| %>
        <%= day.label :missed %>
        <%= day.check_box :missed %> <br/>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= habit.submit "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

And the "magic" happens in the `habits_controller`, which looks like this:

```
class HabitsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @habit = @user.habits.new
    @level = @habit.levels.new
    3.times { @level.days.build }
  end

  def create
    @habit = @user.habits.new(habit_params)
    @levels = @habit.levels

    if @habit.save
      @habit.evaluate(@user) 
      redirect_to ...
    else
      ...
    end
  end

...
  private

  def habit_params 
    params.require(:habit).permit(
      :user_id,
      levels_attributes:[
      :passed,
      days_attributes:[
      :missed,:level_id]])
  end
...  
end
```

Note the `nested strong params`,  the `@habit.evalulate(@user)` method, which I'll show below, and the `3.times { @level.days.build }` call, which builds the fields for the nested form in your view.

**habit.evauate(user) method:** 
This method is called after a new `Habit` is saved. Attributes are evaluated and ids of missed days and levels get appended to user's  `missed_days` and `missed_levels` attributes respectively. The logic is a bit clunky since you'll be appending one Array to another, so you can probably come up with something more efficient. Meanwhile:

```
  def evaluate(user)
    levels.each { |level| level.evaluate }
    user.missed_levels << levels.where(passed: false).ids 
    user.missed_days << days.where(missed: true).ids 
    user.save
  end
```

note the call to `level.evaluate`, which looks like this:

```
  def evaluate
    if days.where(missed: true ).count == 3
      update_attributes(passed: false)
    else
      update_attributes(passed: true)
    end
  end
```

The schema would look like this:

```
  create_table "days", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "level_id"
    t.integer "habit_id"
    t.boolean "missed",   default: false
  end

  create_table "habits", force: true do |t|
    ...
    t.integer "user_id"
    ...
  end

  create_table "levels", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "habit_id"
    t.boolean "passed",   default: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    ...
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "missed_days" #serialize to Array #serialize to Array in model
    t.text     "missed_levels" #serialize to Array in model
    ...
  end
```

And don't forget to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :levels, :days` for the **Habit** model, and  `accepts_nested_attributes_for :days` **User**. **[Here is a git with all my code.](https://github.com/dimanyc/so_prob.git)** Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your response! What I was saying is if a User checks off he `:missed` three days in one level he has to restart the level. Sorry for the strike confusion. I was playing off of "3 strikes you're out." I'll update the question above to elaborate more.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I am thinking that `level` should be a separate model. Give me a few, I am going to update my answer

Comment: Hey Dimitry, any luck? I know I'm not having any. I've been stuck on this problem for 2 weeks now.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com yep, almost there. Will post my update by tonight

Comment: @Dimitry_N definitely. [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) please!

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com have a read at this article to understand what is Dimitry taking about: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Comment: Thanks @dgilperez for the awesome resources. I'll have to sit down later to really grasp them.

Comment: @Dimitry_N this answer is amazing! I didn't know we'd have to spice things up this much. I'm getting a few errors I'd love to run by you in chat.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com sure. send an invite

Comment: @Dimitry_N thanks again for your help! Since we couldn't resolve one bug relating to your answer I continued the conversation over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933272/how-to-fix-level-rb-to-work-with-committed-days